# TMP36, trouble understanding the schematic

Tags: sensor, circuit-analysis, adc

Big electronic noob here. I've got a microcontroller with an ADC (connected to TEMP3) and I'd like to work out the temperature using a TMP36 connected on P11. 
It's output pin is connected on 2, where I measure around 3.1V (environment temperature is around 20 degrees C). I'm clearly seeing the voltage change if I heat up or cool down the TMP36. For example, at around 30 degrees the voltage drops to around 3.0V.

The datasheet says that I should get something around 0.6V at this temperature, and it should rise as the temperature goes up.

Clearly the circuit is changing this, but I can't quite work out how.

[image: TMP36 schematic]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [TMP36](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/TMP35_36_37.pdf) is designed to source current, not to sink it. Get rid of R29. R33 is okay if you need a defined behavior when the sensor is disconnected. Check the maximum self-heating error for whatever load you add to ground.

[image]

Comment: I unfortunately do not have a soldering iron suitable for SMD work. Could you suggest a different temperature sensor which does sink current?

Comment: Offhand, no. Suggest you get someone with soldering skills to help you with it- any kind of soldering iron can be used to remove a single 0603 resistor. Or, better, practice removing resistors of a similar size from a scrap board and get good at it yourself.

Comment: Just to confirm: Moving the resistor fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The datasheet shows direct connection to a DM or ADC which may have 1M
>   to ground. In other cases 100k to ground.  For long cables , special
>   circuits are used.
>
> Output Voltage at 25°C (mV) Table 4.

TMP36 Output

> Characteristics

- Offset Voltage (V) 0.5V
- Output Voltage Scaling (mV/°C)  10
- Output Voltage 25'C  0.75 V

  > thus 30'C 0.80 V